# Why doesn't work the proxy in vite config in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, proxy, vite

I want just to add a simple proxy like:

```
server: {
        port: 8000,
        proxy:{
            '/api':{
                target:'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
                changeOrigin:true,
            }
        }
    },
```

In console I get always GET http://localhost:8000/api 404 (Not Found)

I would expect like

```
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com
```

The fetch request looks like this:

```
const res = await fetch('/api')
const data = await res.json()
console.log(data)
```

Could you please tell what am I doing wront?

Comment: That Vite config sets up Vite's dev server (only used for local development). Vite doesn't bundle the dev server into your app, so that config has no effect in production.